# Using NodaTime to parse an input and output different dateTime formats

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I am currently using NodaTime to parse dates and output dates

```
public static string nodaTimeTest6(string input)
{
    var defaultValue = new OffsetDateTime(new LocalDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), Offset.Zero);
    var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sso<m>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
    var result = pattern.Parse(input);

    return result.Value.Month + "/" + result.Value.Day + "/" + result.Value.Year + " " + result.Value.ClockHourOfHalfDay;
}
```

The input, for example, is this: `2014-03-11T02:00:00-07:00`

If my `return` statement is the following: `return result.Value.ToString()`, then the output would look like this: `2014-03-11T02:00:00-07`

I understand the use of properties with NodaTime (which is a life saver), however, I am interested in outputs like this:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

`yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`

`dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm`

So I tried to change my `return` statement to this:

`return result.Value.Month + "/" + result.Value.Day + "/" + result.Value.Year + " " + result.Value.Hour + ":" + result.Value.Minute;`

The final output of that format is: `3/11/2014 2:0`

Is there anyway to craft the output so it's a fixed format like `03/11/2014 02:00`

I know that if I input an `01` as my month, the output would be `1/11/2014` instead of `01/11/2014`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send the format to the `ToString` method:

```
return result.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't notice this. I relied on muscle memory, didn't think that `.ToString()` has custom parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As ANeves mentions, you can use the BCL-style formatting using `ToString(pattern, IFormatProvider)`, but it's also worth noting that all pattern objects already support a `Format(value)` method in addition to `Parse(string)`, so you could also write:

```
var displayPattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, defaultValue);
return displayPattern.Format(result.Value);
```

Which is perhaps more consistent with using patterns for parsing, and also happens to be more efficient if you can keep hold of the pattern and use it more than once.

The Noda Time user guide has a section on [Text handling](http://nodatime.org/userguide/text.html) that covers this in more detail.

Not directly related to your question, but: if you're formatting an `OffsetDateTime` for display without including the offset, you'd normally want to convert it to a `LocalDateTime` (perhaps with a fixed-offset time zone) to ensure that the results are comparable.  As it stands, you'll return the same string for inputs of `2014-03-11T02:00:00-07:00` and also e.g. `2014-03-11T02:00:00-08:00`.  Perhaps that's okay for your use case.